# Efficient filtering of many files by their content with awk/sed/grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to list all files within a directory (recursively) that have their second lines wholly matching a certain regular expression. The total number of files is about 60K.

So far, I composed this command:
`find /path -type f | xargs --no-run-if-empty -n1000 awk 'FNR = 2 && $0 ~ /^regular expression$/ {print FILENAME; nextfile}'`.

Can it be made more efficient?

Comment: You are not saying anything about the size of the files. This could make a difference if they are large: do a `nextfile` even in the case the line does not match.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your directory and files?

Comment: Files are in the order of 100KB. They are the nginx cache.

Answer (score 2):

First beware that you mistakenly used `=` instead of the correct `==`.

You do not need `xargs`, you could run directly from `find`. Also as your `awk` should exit as soon as it processed line 2 instead of reading the whole file.

```
find /path -type f -exec awk 'FNR == 2 && /^regular expression$/ {print FILENAME}; FNR == 2 {nextfile}' '{}' +
```

The `+` at the end of the `-exec` argument instructs `find` to put as many file name arguments as possible. À-la `xargs`. See [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) documentation.

The important point here is `FNR==2 {nextfile}`.

Whether `-exec` is better than `xargs` (but use `-print0` & `-0` if available) is subject to discussions. On the one hand `find … | xargs …` allows some parallelization with `find` reading some more file names while `awk` inspects a previous batch. On the other hand the parallelization could result in bad disk trashing with `awk` and `find` competing for different tracks of the disk. Your hardware (cache size, SSD, etc.) will change the deal. Profile then decide.

Comment: You could do that, but it would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: 1) I used `xargs` because the files are numerous. 2) What is the meaning of the final `'{}' +`? 3) `==` and another `nextfile` are good points. 4) Your variant is 25% faster than mine (with `==`).

Comment: @Michael Vehrs: any better ideas?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin `find -exec` calls the external command for each matched file. Therefore, your original idea of using `xargs` is better.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs No. With `+` `find` will behave similar to `xargs` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). Still the important point is to bailout of `awk` after reading line two.

Comment: I edited the answer to describe more the performance issues.

Comment: @kmkaplan I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
grep -n <reg expr> /path/to/* | grep ":2:" | cut -d ':' -f1
```

So long as `:2:` is not part of the `<reg expr>`.

There is also `-x` for whole line matching.

No idea if this is quicker - I don't have 60k files to test with :]

Comment: Should be `grep -ran <reg expr> /path/to | grep ":2:" | cut -d ':' -f1`. Somewhat (not radically) slower than my variant.